# How can I get my HP 309G printer to work on Linux Mint 10?

Tags: linux, printing

How can I get my HP 309G printer to work on Linux Mint 10?

It is not recognized out-of-the-box, and HP doesn't supply drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [HPLIP](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/manual/distros/linuxmint.html)
 In Ubuntu you can find it in the sofware center (which there may be something similar in Mint if you are using the Ubuntu based version) or you can try the instructions in the link.
There also seems to be some info in the [Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=58830&start=0).

Comment: The ubuntu (raring) hplip package works (printing and scanning) for my HP 309G.